# Navigation Drawer opening with clicking on toolbar search

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I am working on an app that has a bottom navigation menu, a navigation drawer, and a search function in the toolbar.  I have all but 1 thing working right now - The problem that I am experiencing is that when I click on the "search icon" in the toolbar, the drawer is also opening!  I really don't understand why!  I'm sure this is something simple that I just cannot see, but . . .

Anyway, can someone please help!

NavigationActivity.kt

```
class NavigationActivity  : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    
    lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    lateinit var navController: NavController
    lateinit var navView: BottomNavigationView
    lateinit var myNavView: NavigationView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation)


        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        myNavView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view) as NavigationView
        myNavView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

        navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        setupBottomNavigation()

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.navigation_map, R.id.navigation_list, R.id.navigation_workmates), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

    }
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController,appBarConfiguration)

    }
    private fun setupBottomNavigation() {
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }


    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)


        val myActionMenuItem = menu!!.findItem(R.id.search)
        var searchView = myActionMenuItem.actionView as SearchView

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                
                toast(query)
                myActionMenuItem.collapseActionView()
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(s: String): Boolean {
                
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                return false
            }
        })
        return true
    }
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {

            val check = drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)
            if (!check) {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
            } else {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
            }
        return true
    }


    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        var selectedOption = ""
        when (item?.itemId) {
            R.id.yourlunch -> selectedOption = "yourLunch"
            R.id.settings -> selectedOption = "settings"
            R.id.logout -> selectedOption = "logout"
        }
        when(selectedOption){
            "yourLunch" ->{
                toast("Your Lunch Selected")
            }
            "settings"->{
                toast("Settings Selected")
            }
            "logout" ->{
                toast("Logout Selected")
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

navigation_drawer_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/yourlunch"
        android:title="@string/your_lunch"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_fastfood_24" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="@string/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:title="@string/logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_power_settings_new_24"/>
</menu>
```

search_memu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: on onOptionsItemSelected method, you defined that when you click on options in the taskbar, it should open the drawer menu. try removing it.

Comment: Oh my goodness . . . I see it now!    THANK YOU!!!!!    Can you tell me how I can distinguish between a click on the Search and a click on the Hamburger Icon?

Comment: I'll write an answer for you :)

Comment: That would be awesome!  That way I can give you credit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on onOptionsItemSelected method, you defined that when you click on options in the taskbar, it should open the drawer menu. try removing it.
if you want to define which item to handle on the taskbar, user code below in onOptionsItemSelected:

```
when(item.getId()){

    R.id.item1 -> ////

    R.id.item2 -> ////

}
```

use the id you gave to the menu items.

Comment: Ok, I see that now.  I did that for the navigation_drawer_menu options, but not for the search function!    One last question . . . How would I find the id of the "hamburger icon" as it is set pragmatically?  I mean the search is obviously R.id.search - but that is because I programmed a menu with that id in it - I didn't program the id for the hamburger.

Comment: It should open the menu when you click on it. you don't need to set it manually. I think you didn't set the menu to your taskbar because if you did, it would have opened the menu when you clicked on the icon automaticly.

Comment: I got it!  I can use the "else" in the switch to do the other stuff I need to do!  YOU ARE AWESOME!!!!  Thank you for your help!

Comment: I did a little research and I think this is the id: android.R.id.home.

Comment: You do not and should not override `onOptionsItemSelected()` just to make the drawer icon work - that's what the default implementation of `onOptionsItemSelected()` already does for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `onOptionsItemSelected()` is not calling `super.onOptionsItemSelected()` - **that** is what automatically dispatches the call for the `android.R.id.home` button and what hooks up the `onSupportNavigateUp()` call.

Given that `onSupportNavigateUp()` is handling the up button for you, you can delete your entire `onOptionsItemSelected()` implementation.

Comment: No, I can't!  I have options inside the drawer that need to be handled separately!

Comment: That isn't the case in the code in your question. Since the code you posted is apparently not your actual code, Is your actual code calling `super.onOptionsItemSelected()`? If it is not, that is what you're missing, as per this answer.

Comment: To say this is not "actual code" would not be totally correct - more that it is not "complete code."  I have a lot to add to this still.  :)  I thank you for the help!  There is still a long way to go with this app!